# How to prove that real numbers are dependent over Q?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question.
Are the following numbers:

$$
Y = 1-\sqrt{2}\\
X= 2+7\sqrt{2}
$$

Dependent over $R$
Are they dependent over $Q$?

I don§t understand what does it mean "numbers are dependent" how can numbers be dependent?

Comment: I think they are talking about 'linear (in)dependence'. They are linear dependent over $\mathbb R$, because there is a $r\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $Y=rX$. When this $r$ is also in $\mathbb Q$, they are also dependent over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: What do you men in "the value of Y is dependent on the value of X"

Comment: $Y$ is dependent on $X$ if there is a (real) scalar (number) $\lambda$ such that $Y=\lambda X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note that the `linear-algebra` tag was on the original Question.  We can consider the nonzero real numbers $X,Y$ as elements of a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$.

In either case $X$ and $Y$ are *linearly dependent* since $X,Y \in \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $XY - YX = 0$ is a linear dependence relation.

In the edited version of the Question we are asked if $X,Y$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$.  They are not, rather they are linear independent.  For if $rX + sY = 0$ for rational numbers $r,s$ not both zero, then $rX = -sY$ and (since now both sides are nonzero):

$$-s/r = X/Y = (2+7\sqrt{2})/(1-\sqrt{2}) = -(16+9\sqrt{2})$$

by rationalizing the denominator (multiply numerator and denominator by $1+\sqrt{2}$).  This is clearly impossible since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: What about Q, are they dependent over Q?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q}$ the rationals they are independent.  You can check this by simplifying $X/Y$ to see that it is not a rational ratio.

Answer (score 1):

To show they are dependent over $\mathbb Q$, you have to show that
$$r=\frac YX=\frac {1-\sqrt{2}}{2+7\sqrt{2}}$$
is in $\mathbb Q$, so you assume $r=\frac pq$ for coprime integers $p$ and $q$, and solve for $p$ and $q$. Probably you end up with something like $2p^2=q^2$, but that is not possible, because a square has each prime factor an even number of times in its factorization.

Comment: Rationalize the denominator and the result will be clear.